# Triggers corrupt merge replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, trigger, merge-replication

I have merge replication (SQL server 2014) and a table that have 3 triggers that monitor delete, insert and update.
All of the triggers are after trigger not instead of.

I'm updating the value on one side and it doesn't update on the second server and when I'm disabling the triggers it's all working.
insert and delete doesn't work as well.
Any thoughts ?

Comment: [Control Behavior of Triggers and Constraints in Synchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/control-behavior-of-triggers-and-constraints-in-synchronization?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Well as McNets answered all i had to do is alter the script.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG]
ON [dbo].[Table] AFTER DELETE
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
AS
    BEGIN
        BLA BLA BLA
    END
```